# Failed to allocate varyings on Samsung devices [OpenGL ES]

Tags: android, opengl-es, fragment-shader

Compiling blur shader on Samsung devices fails with error: **Failed to allocate varyings**

The shader code is the following:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords[14];
varying vec2 pixel_size;

uniform vec2 v_resolution;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main()
{
     ...
}
```

On other devices works good, what might be wrong with Samsung devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're simply exceeding the number of varyings supported by your implementation. The maximum number of varying vectors can be queried with:

```
GLint maxVarying == 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VARYING_VECTORS, &maxVarying);
```

The minimum required limit for a compliant implementation is 8. This means that at least 8 varyings of type `vec4` are supported.

Your case is interesting because you use a total of 16 varyings of type `vec2`. You may think that this will fit into the space of 8 `vec4` values, and should therefore work on all devices. But it's more complicated than that.

The hairy details on this topic can be found in Appendix A.7 starting on page 111 of the GLES 1.00 spec, titled "Counting of Varyings and Uniforms". It's about 2.5 pages of very technical description which I won't be able to repeat here. But essentially, it describes a possible packing algorithm that implementations **can** use while being compliant. They could use something that packs more effectively, but they do not have to.

One key part in this packing algorithm that applies to your case is the following:

> Vectors always occupy  registers in a single row.  Elements of an array must be in different rows. E.g. vec4 will always occupy one row; float[8] will occupy one column.  Since it is not permitted to split a variable, large arrays e.g.. for varyings, float[16] will always fail with this algorithm.

This means that for an implementation that supports only 8 varying vectors, and that uses this compliant algorithm, you can **not** fit your array of 14 `vec2` values. It could fit 16 single values of type `vec2`. Or for example an array of 8 `vec2` values and 8 single values of type `vec2`, if I understand the spec correctly. But not one array with size larger than 8.

For your shader to compile safely, you will need an implementation that returns at least 14 for the `GL_MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` limit.

Comment: The disappointing thing from a performance point of view is that packing those UV coordinates into vec4s will break make the texture reads into dependent texture reads and break texture pre-fetch optimisations on a lot GPUs.

But it's better for it to work slightly slower than not work at all.

Comment: @Reto: nice answer ! However something is puzzling me a bit : most recent Samsung phones are equiped with Adreno >= 320 or Mali GPUs and they seems to have all MAX_VARYING_VECTORS >= 15... The only exception to this would be the Galaxy S3 (i9300) with a value of 12 but this is a rather old phone ... So I am wondering on which Samsung device OP is actually testing ...

Answer (score 1):

This question really helped me out.

I wound up splitting up the array and it worked fine:

```
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords0;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords1;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords2;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords3;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords4;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords5;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords6;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords7;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords8;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords9;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords10;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords11;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords12;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords13;
```